# Mvvm Light, UWP and code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

Base on [this excellent presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrcVQGTXZKM) from Laurent Bugnion at Xamarin Evolve 2014, I'm trying to create my first UWP/MVVM Light application.

I created a very simple *Article : ObservableObject* class with 2 string properties : *Référence* and *Désignation*.

In the view model associated to the article list view, I have an action to create a new article :

```
    public ArticlesViewModel(IArticleService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        ArticleService = dataService;
        NavigationService = navigationService;

        CréeArticleCommand = new RelayCommand(CréeArticle);
    }

    public RelayCommand CréeArticleCommand { get; private set; }

    private void CréeArticle()
    {
        if (!CréeArticleCommand.CanExecute(null))
            return;

        NavigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.ArticleDetail_Key,
                                     new ArticleViewModel(new Article(),
                                                          ArticleService,
                                                          NavigationService));
    }
```

here is the XAML for my Article detail view :

```
<!-- language: xaml -->
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniversalTest1.UWP.Articles"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Editors="using:DevExpress.UI.Xaml.Editors"
    x:Class="UniversalTest1.UWP.Articles.Article_Detail"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UniversalTest1.Data.ViewModels.Articles;assembly=UniversalTest1.Data"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ArticleViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Référence :"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Désignation :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <Editors:TextEdit Text="{Binding Article.Référence, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
        <Editors:TextEdit Text="{Binding Article.Désignation, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>

        <Button Content="Sauver" Command="{Binding SauverCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My problem here is that I have to define the DataContext in the code behind of my page :

```
public sealed partial class Article_Detail : Page
{
    public Article_Detail()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        DataContext = (ArticleViewModel)e.Parameter;
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to keep the design time DataContext as defined in the d:DataContext part of the Xaml's Page, and at runtime, get the DataContext from the Navigation parameter ?**

My goal here is to have the less amount possible of code in the code behind. So I would like to define the runtime DataContext in the XAML also.

Comment: Just an advice from another french guy: you should never use accentuated characters in your classes members/methods. Just use ACSII characters to avoid any errors.

Comment: Arnaud, we could debate this for hours :) To make my point, I've used accents for more than 10 years in C#. I ask my developers (ok, I force them) to do so because 1/ I've never had any errors because of that, Visual Studio manages perfectly Unicode files 2/ It makes the code much more readable 3/ I have the feeling that your idea comes from old time languages (I've used Delphi for years before the .Net time)

Comment: @JulienFerraro You should avoid french in any code which can be, someday, be read by a non french speaker. Here you are destroying at least two [naiming conventions](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainnaming.html). Keep it clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of dependency injection to create design or runtime service instances for your viewmodel. Using a view model locator you can do something like this:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IArticleService>())
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IArticleService, DesignArticleService>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IArticleService>())
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IArticleService, ArticleService>();
            }
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ArticleViewModel>();
    }

    public ArticleViewModel ArticleViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ArticleViewModel>();
}
```

And in your App.xaml you register the locator

```
<Application
    x:Class="UniversalTest1.App" // your namespace
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModel="using:UniversalTest1.Data.ViewModels"> // your namespace

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

And then you can reference it in your xaml like this:

```
<Page
...
DataContext="{Binding ArticleViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

You could also take a look at the sample code here https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Flowers/Flowers.Data/ViewModel/ViewModelLocator.cs

Comment: Hosney, thank you for your prompt answer. Anyway, my question was not exactly this. I have pretty much exactly the same code as the one you show in my solution. Please have a look at the Flowers.Wp/DetailsPage.xaml in the sample. The DataContext is defined for design time. The runtime data context is defined in the code behind. My question is : Why should we define the runtime data context in the code behind.

Comment: @JulienFerraro it doesn't have to be that way. I have specified the DataContext only in the xaml in the code above. No code behind. The locator decides which service instance to return based on if the application is running or in design mode.

Comment: Check out Flowers.Wp/MainPage.xaml in the sample. It uses the same concept.

Comment: Hosney, my main page has the exact same binding as the Flowers.Wp/MainPage.xaml.
The page I'm talking about is a detail view, like Flowers.Wp/DetailsPage.xaml.
Why is the binding different in Flowers.Wp/MainPage.xaml and in Flowers.Wp/DetailsPage.xaml ?

Comment: @JulienFerraro I'm not sure why the example is done that way but it doesn't have to be that way. You can bind to the datacontext directly in your details page the same way you do in the main page.

Comment: No, the designer will bind to the DataContext you provide. In the above code the ViewModelLocator injects the DesignArticleService if the ViewModel is requested from the designer. You can use this to return design time values.

Comment: Hosney, you're right this works. But my ArticleViewModal has 2 constructors, like in the FlowerViewModel from LaurentBugnion. You have to decorate the design time constructor with the PreferredConstructor attribute. If you don't, you get an exception "Cannot register: Multiple constructors found in ArticleViewModel but none marked with PreferredConstructor"

Comment: Correct. You have only one in the code provided though so I assumed you had just the one constructor. Great that it works!

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to use your own implementation of `NavigationService`. The concept is to navigate to your page and call your *ViewModel* at the same time to handle parameters and set the *DataContext*.

Here are two samples of this pattern:

- Prism: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/Navigation/FrameNavigationService.cs
- Template10: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Services/NavigationService/NavigationService.cs